# Why am I getting TemplateSyntaxError at 'bootstrap4' is not a registered tag library?

Tags: python, django

I'm making my way through the Django project in Python Crash Course, and I've run into the following error:

'bootstrap4' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of: admin_list admin_modify admin_urls cache i18n l10n log static tz

```
1   {% load bootstrap4 %}
2   
3   <!DOCTYPE html>
4   <html lang="en">
5     <head>
6       <meta charset="utf-8">
7       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
8       <title>Learning Log</title>
9   
10      {% bootstrap_css %}
11      {% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
```

I've included it in my Installed apps, as seen:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
# My apps
'learning_logs',
'users',

# Third party apps.
'bootstrap4',

# Default Django apps.
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

And it appears fine in my base.html file too:

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Learning Log</title>

    {% bootstrap_css %}
    {% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light mb-4 border">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'learning_logs:index'%}">Learning Log</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics'%}">Topics</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navbar-text">Hello, {{ user.username }}.</span>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:logout' %}">Log out</a>
          </li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:register' %}">Register</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link "href="{% url 'users:login' %}">Log in</a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}

      </ul>

    </div>

    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="pb-2 mb-2 border-bottom">
        {% block page_header %}{% endblock page_header %}
      </div>
      <div>
        {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
      </div>
    </main>

  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea why I'm running into this error? I really can't seem to figure it out - any help appreciated.

Cheers,
D

Comment: Did you try stopping your django server and restarting it ?

Comment: Is there any relationship between the first excerpt and the second?

Comment: Did you install django-boostrap4? `pip install django-bootstrap4` Also, did you save settings.py after modifying `INSTALLED_APPS`?